# Freebase image URL -- rate limits

Tags: google-api, freebase

Do Freebase image URLs need to be provided with a `key` as well? ("as well" as the other API's such as `mqlread`, `topic`, etc.)

The documentation (the one place in the doc that mentions these URLs at all...) does not mention that. However, `freebase.com` does create images with a key, and when I neglect to provide one I sometimes get the 403 error "Daily Quota Exceeded".

If I *do* need to provide a key, it will be a client-key that I am providing, correct? (Assuming I am generating URLs for the browser to fetch).

If so -- what are the differences between the client and the server keys? Are their quotas separate? Does an image fetch count as "one API read operation"?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've already determined that the key is required.  I think quotas are aggregated for applications (and perhaps users), so if you had both client and server keys generated (or multiples of either), they'd all share the same quota.  Which type of key you want really depends more on where it's being used and how you want to manage access.  For example, server keys can be restricted by IP address which obviously won't work for client keys.